# Katex showing duplicate equations

Tags: html, jekyll, katex

I am currently using Jekyll to render markdown to html which uses Katex for math equations.
I have the following lines in the markdown file

```
$$
\begin{align}
A & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{align}
$$

$$
e = mc^2
$$
```

And following is what I got on my webpage a text version of the equation beside the latex rendered equation.

[image]

The following is my `_config.yml`

```
highlighter: rouge
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/
environment: prod
# url: 
plugins:
  - jekyll-scholar
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-katex
kramdown:
  math_engine: katex
markdown: kramdown
usemathjax: true
katex:
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using `\begin{aligned}` instead of `align`